# Permission denied. HttpSocket in Cake php is not working

Tags: php, cakephp, amazon-web-services

I'm getting "Permission denied" when calling `HttpSocket`.
It was working when it was in production server. In production server we used Xamp. We recently deployed it in AWS server. Where we tried installing xamp and then manually installed PHP, Apache and MySQL. After that we are facing this problem in our AWS server.

What might be gone wrong? I had already posted this question, but I didn't get any reply over there, may be because I posted it on Saturday evening.

Permission denied

```
Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.
Stack Trace

    CORE/Cake/Network/CakeSocket.php line 272 → CakeSocket->connect()
    CORE/Cake/Network/Http/HttpSocket.php line 371 → CakeSocket->write(string)
    CORE/Cake/Network/Http/HttpSocket.php line 459 → HttpSocket->request(array)
    APP/Controller/CampaignsController.php line 563 → HttpSocket->get(string)
    [internal function] → CampaignsController->createcampaign()
    CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php line 490 → ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(CampaignsController, array)
    CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 191 → Controller->invokeAction(CakeRequest)
    CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 165 → Dispatcher->_invoke(CampaignsController, CakeRequest)
    APP/webroot/index.php line 113 → Dispatcher->dispatch(CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
```

I'm totally blocked. Any help from you is greatly appreciated. Please feel free to ask if had any queries to resolve the issue.

Comment: first set debug 2 then check error .

Comment: Hi mate, debug is already set to 2. and i got the above error.

Comment: The reason for no answers is probably more because of the lack of information and because of no signs of any debugging attempts. It's most probably a configuration problem, but without further information there's not much anyone can do from here other than guessing.

Comment: further information? What kind of ?

Comment: Environment details (OS, network related configuration, possible usage of security extensions/modules like SELinux, etc..), `HttpSocket` options used, your debugging attempts, etc. It's pretty much impossible to reproduce your problem without knowing appropriate details, so your only chance would be someone coming along who's used the same setup by chance, and eventually had the same problem, and I kinda doubt that will happen. ps, use @username when replying to make sure the user get's notified about your comment.

Comment: @ndm sorry for not tagging the name. I'm using CENTOS and i don't know the network related configs. If you specify i will say

Comment: @ndm Thankyou. I understood there is some problem in config settings. So installed xampp as in our test server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I got solution for my question. I uninstalled my php and installed xampp in our server, from then it started working fine. There might be some changes in ini settings, but now I don't have any issues.